# What relay is suitable for a submersible water pump

Tags: ac, relay, dc, water

I have an AC submersible water pump with the following ratings:

```
Voltage: 165v-250v/50Hz
Power 18W
H-max 1.8 meters
Output: 1200L/h
```

My mains voltage is `225V to 250V`

I need the specs of a relay ( 9v DC to AC ) for this. From the pump specs, I am thinking the current required would be  `I = 18/250v`, which is `72 milliamperes` (hope I am right).  Please suggest a good relay for this.  I already have a Songle relay shield (see pic)
[image]

with the following rating

```
5v DC 
10 A 250v ac 10A 125V ac
10 A 30 v DC 10A 30V DC
```

Although it's not a `9V DC`, I still wanted to know if that would work.

Comment: The single relay shield looks fine for me

Answer (score 1):

The switch ratings of the relay must be at least what you want to use it with, which is the case for your relay:

```
use with 220/230V, rated 250VAC
use with 0.072A, rated 10A
```

That module has 5V relays, why do you want 9V? You could use an 7805 to reduce 9V to 5V.

Answer (score 0):

That [particular relay](https://www.ghielectronics.com/downloads/man/20084141716341001RelayX1.pdf) is not rated for motor or inductive load at 240VAC (or anything over 120VAC).

[image]

That's a separate question from "will it work", but it is not going to be within the manufacturer's ratings.

Comment: True but the resistive component of an 18W motor is likely to be large enough that a "7A resistive" rating is likely to be adequate.

Comment: @BrianDrummond Maybe with a 250VAC bipolar TVS across the load- I'd worry the contact gap isn't adequate to prevent excessive arcing on opening. I'm not worried about the starting surge, as you suggest it should be no issue. The lower voltage rating is a hint as to the cause of the limitation, I think.

Comment: Good point, worth making.

Comment: Ok, I wont use this due to the Inductive load issue, is there a relay you can suggest?